# Entity Framework Order of Operations

Tags: entity-framework

I have a transaction type system where an object is created and stored and then sent off to another service for further processing and then the object is updated upon return.  I have been doing some quality checks in my system and I noticed that a handful of records are logged in the secondary system but not in my main application.  Is this possible?  Does context.savechanges() move on before returning a result?

Comment: EF 6+ supports [asynchronous `SaveChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx) via `SaveChangesAsync`, but normal SaveChanges is always synchronous.  Have you checked if there are DB errors, threading errors, or other exceptions that may be blocking the record from being logged in the first system?

Comment: Thanks just.another.programmer.  I have checked the logs on the server and there is nothing consistent to indicate a failure.  In the last week I have spotted 20 of these errors over 5,000 inserts.  Could you suggest anything I can try to catch these type of errors?